# How to parse data from intent in Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, android-intent

I'm trying to get data from an `Intent`. It is passed as an array of `Float` containing one element.  I tried this code, but it crashes:

```
procedure TMainScreen.BroadcastReceiver2Receive(Context: JContext; Intent: JIntent);
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
var
  Temp: String;
  Hr1: single;
  Bundle :Jbundle;
begin
  button2.Text:= 'triggered';
  if Intent.hasExtra(stringtojstring('DATA')) = true then
  begin
    bundle := intent.getExtras();
    button1.Text:= 'got data';
    hr1:= bundle.getFloatArray(stringtojstring('DATA'))[0];
    button2.Text:= floattostr(hr1);
  end;
{$ELSE}
begin
{$ENDIF}
end;
```

I'm sure I'm not dealing with the array correctly. How do I do it?

Comment: How does it crash exactly? (Is there smoke rising, a bad smell ...)

Comment: Note that your `{$IFDEF}` is placed wrong.  Your code would not compile on non-Android platforms due to the `JContext` and `JIntent` parameters.  The entire method needs to be wrapped in `{$IFDEF}`, not just its body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `JIntent.getFloatArrayExtra()` instead of `JIntent.getExtras()`.

But, either way, before accessing the array element, you need to check if the returned array is `nil` or not.  If it is not, you *should* also check that the array length is actually > 0.

Try something more like this:

```
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
procedure TMainScreen.BroadcastReceiver2Receive(Context: JContext; Intent: JIntent);
var
  DataStr: JString;
  Arr: TJavaArray<Single>;
  Hr1: single;
begin
  Button2.Text := 'triggered';
  DataStr := StringToJString('DATA');
  if Intent.hasExtra(DataStr) then
  begin
    Button1.Text := 'got data';
    Arr := Intent.getFloatArrayExtra(DataStr);
    if (Arr <> nil) and (Arr.Length > 0) then
    begin
      Hr1 := Arr[0];
      Button2.Text := FloatToStr(Hr1);
    end else
      Button2.Text := 'no value';
  end;
end;
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! What is the best way to grab few data packets in a row? I have 2 intents, one with just 'DATA', another with 3 headers: 'MIN', 'MAX' and 'SUM'. I've used your code 3 times with different DataStr filter and works. But sometimes the app is closing itself. Am I missing something? Also, I couldn't make my own receiver, so I'm using this component https://github.com/barisatalay/delphi-android-broadcast-receiver-component  but I'm not sure whether it is the best way to do it. Could you share some examples, please?  Thanks again, you saved my day =)

Comment: @MonZon: If your app closes before all of the `Intent`s are received, there is nothing you can do about that. If you receive one `Intent` and are expecting another, don't close the app until after it is received. Or, are you saying that your handing of the `Intent`s is crashing your app, that is why your app closes?

Comment: @MonZon: As for the best way to implement a broadcast receiver, that needs to be posted as a new question.

Comment: the app crashes once or twice right after I receive first intents, after that it works normal. That's weird...

Comment: btw here is the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46204944/the-best-way-to-receive-multiple-intents-in-delphi-android =))

Comment: @MonZon: First, all you did was take your earlier comment and copy it into a new question. That is a bad way to ask questions, and you didn't provide any useful/new details, so it is not answerable in its current state. Second, you asked two separate questions, one about the crashing and one about the broadcast receiver. I said only the broadcast receiver portion should be a new question. And even then, it is actually off-topic for StackOverflow, since you are asking for a recommendation or code review. If the receiver you already have works, use it. If not, ask specific questions about it

Comment: @MonZon: What is the ACTUAL problem you are having with receiving multiple `Intent` events? Please show your actual code, and explain what you expect from it, and what it is actually doing (or not doing) instead.

Comment: in this question or should I create a new one? Your code works perfectly.

Comment: @MonZon: in a new question, since this one is already answered as asked. And make sure the new question is complete, has all relevant details and code, etc. Refer to this question if you want, but people need to be able to answer a new question on its own.